# Can I make latexmk quieter?

Tags: warnings, latexmk

I'm using `latexmk -quiet`, and while it suppresses most status messages, there are still a few irrelevant messages that it gives me:

```
$ latexmk -pdf -silent document.tex
Latexmk: Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
Latexmk: Running 'pdflatex  -interaction=batchmode  "document.tex"'
This is pdfTeXk, Version 3.1415926-1.40.9 (Web2C 7.5.7)
 %&-line parsing enabled.
entering extended mode
Latexmk: Citation `mycite' on page 3 undefined 
Latexmk: Reference `fig:myfig' on page 4 undefined
```

and so on. All of the citations and references are eventually defined through re-running LaTeX, so these are extraneous and distracting, as well.

Using `latexmk -quiet -silent` doesn't appear to change anything.

I was using Rubber, which deals with this very well, but unfortunately lacks some features Latexmk has in other areas (such as `chapterbib` support and dependency output).

Comment: I got annoyed from the printing of included file names and had to comment the code line in the Perl script. If you have some basic knowledge you can search for the code lines in question and disable them by putting the `#` comment character in front of it.

Comment: Just FYI: according to the `man` page, `-silent` and `-quiet` are equivalent. (So it's no surprise that calling with both doesn't improve anything.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I agree that many of `latexmk`'s messages should not appear when the `-quiet` option is used.  The messages about undefined messages really are only needed for the last run; but implementing that would need some changes in the logic.

I'll add that to the list of improvements.  Also it might be worth having a super-quiet mode as well as a quiet mode.  Super-quiet mode would be like `rubber`'s quiet mode, which I find too laconic; but that's an issue of personal preference.

Comment: Personally, I prefer to only see output when there's actually something I need to address (warnings or errors), rather than diagnostic messages that leave me in the habit of ignoring the output, and therefore sometimes missing an important warning.

Comment: Is there a way to have quiet specified but still show the errors?

Comment: `pdflatex -halt-on-error %O %S | grep -A3 '^!'` hides most of the output, halts on an error, and displays the error.